# Rails App (Spree) - Sudden "Uncaught Type Error"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a fresh 3.0 version installation of Spree Commerce running on my Rails app. I added Slick Slider (slick.js) to my installation using the following methods:

Added slick.js to vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend

Put the relevant SCSS files in vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend

setup a custom homepage Deface layout, and then called slick slider at the bottom using `<script></script>`

It all worked swimmingly, and I even setup some slick-custom.scss styling. So I commit changes, shut-off Codekit, and then move locations. Open my Macbook again and suddenly it's throwing a blasted **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**. It is called on `$(".slider-for").slick({` ...

I have been all up and down this thing, and I cannot tell what's changed, nor why it isn't loading. Slick is in resources, jQuery is loaded, filepaths and elements are all named appropriately. It's driving me insane, and I don't know what to do.

Relevant files:

Homepage setup

```
<div class="slider-for">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div>
          <div class="product-image">
            <%= link_to product_image(product), product %>
          </div>
          <div class="product-info">
            <h2 class="product-title"><%= product.name %></h2>
            <div class="product-description">
              <%= product.description.to_s.html_safe %>
            </div>
            <div class="product-link">
                <div class="product-price">
                  <%= product.display_price %>
                </div>
                <div class="product-more">
                  <%= link_to "Read More", product, class: "more-link" %>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div class="slider-nav">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div>
            <div class="product-image">
              <%= product_image(product) %>
            </div>
            <h4 class="product-title"><%= product.name %></h4>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".slider-for").slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,
      asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
    });
    $(".slider-nav").slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.slider-for',
      dots: true,
      centerMode: true,
      focusOnSelect: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

Head section:

```
<head data-hook="inside_head">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Grand on Oak Boutique Store - Grand on Oak</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
<meta name="keywords" content="boutique, boutique shop, clothing, clothing store">
<meta name="description" content="High-end shopping in Conway, Arkansas">
<link href="http://grandonoak.com/" rel="canonical">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon-69231eed30cd5a922a19b067ccf8b243.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/spree/frontend/frontend_bootstrap-f5a4d0dbd069cabee02f14c2de1040d5.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/spree/frontend-c946bacb82835ce1f9a9de94acfa7948.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/spree/frontend/_variables-75e303a624880e205110a476763b276e.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/spree/frontend/all-a523e282aabcd1ab0ec90f62c8f67344.css?body=1">
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="QD3LmjLGnTCtGkIX9NZw/W9UK5cP+LTB+aW5fQOErSCb/RgsfNOWvKDMNOJxbjXHkO5TS91cE54nKYDPeZJyow==">
<script src="/assets/jquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs-e27bd20a10d28155845a22d71ef94f2f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix-86647d01ace516e05ddf78d2b6e85e20.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert-2a2796d28d7833f423ee421a3ad297bb.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button-6b326d9b5034209f30109e77c264a190.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel-31dbb9c732fc2da02b8d5a97d9ae0047.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse-624b0c6035c65b5be6ae581d8dc4e196.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown-ce1bbc536745c41510513f7274f9897c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal-77a0e72df31a788e4f6a3f28370eb69e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy-3892c697f57b7e7b9d5993044235a210.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab-6f45b70c6440bd0222c171dd7a926b5d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition-264673896da1e31c3b865db964cd6592.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip-718496fb53635605964fb77613425c8d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover-3dcfaa462d273d183ef52064ce120a5b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets-830839b3b00123a30d090955aa74da5c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min-2d81074928b8de12627110241d1e7b82.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jsuri-b9ca271e978b987b894cb0a92de921d9.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/spree-8ac8776671ec803cc33e03272659d498.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/spree/frontend/cart-1590808ff9329c79b63acdc5a84bc498.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.payment-99cc3707e9b4c29e1d1be187415f6415.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/spree/frontend/checkout-82e3443fe70333ace69246f9b31b9507.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/spree/frontend/checkout/address-616b9ad86f44c5fa74398e99accc9eee.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/spree/frontend/checkout/payment-4df84c09e7418b7aa6394f472f10fec9.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/spree/frontend/product-09bee3d334f4f5507d01406128c60330.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/spree/frontend-54fe02bb1f643864d4c75b951a66652e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/spree/frontend/slick-6fd6b8e406e07fa296d234cc3a4b2a72.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/spree/frontend/all-5a6ef0f53abed7a46fdc4793b7e2a630.js?body=1"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    <link rel="next" href="/?page=2">


  </head>
```

All Slick Slider files are concurrent with Git master. Have tried variations, but currently have slick.js, slick.scss, slick-theme.scss in appropriate root folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted out! Because I used Heroku to deploy after initial Rails install, I had a bunch of precompiled assets that were apparently causing problems.

If jQuery is acting a fool for no obvious reason, just delete public/assets and you'll be good to go. Optionally, I'd think you could also re-precompile and that'd do the trick.

Hope this helps someone else out! Rookie mistake on my part, I'm sure, but I definitely ended up a day behind schedule because of it.